# How to remove duplicate rows from cartesian product dataframe using python

Tags: python

I have a cartesian product of two dataframes as my input.

I want to remove the duplicate rows from the cartesian product dataframe. And I have over 100+ rows in the dataframe, so want to loop through as well.

Example : I want to remove (2,0) from the input as it is a duplicate of (0,2)

```
**Input**
(0,0),(0,2),(1,1),(2,0)

**Expected Output**
(0,0),(0,2)
(1,1)
```

Comment: Could you please share what you've tried so far ?

Comment: why is the (1,1) on a different line here?
is it because of the x coordinate?
and depending on what the data represents, (0,2) and (2,0) are no duplicates at all, so i would recommend changing title

Comment: The input and output you posted are lists of `tuple`s. If you want help regarding `pandas` dataframe, please post samples relevant to dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

a very inefficient but working method is:

```
[data for index, data in enumerate(Input) if data not in Input[:index] and (data[1], data[0]) not in Input[:index]]
```

writing this more clearly becomes:

```
for i in range(length(Input)):
    data = Input[i]
    data2 = (data[1], data[0])
    for j in range(Output):
        if data == Output[j] or data2 == Output[j] :
            break
    else:  # only happens if for loop completes naturally, without a break
        Output.append(Input[i])
```

considering (2,0) and (0,2) are duplicates, we could also do this more efficiently for larger number of items:
apply any sorting algorithm where you sort on the datapoints internally a well, (for example always largest number first). Now you can just check an item with it's neighbour to know if it is a duplicate or not. This means that we have
O(n*logn)+O(n) which is O(n*logn) total, while the previous answer was O(n²)

lastly, you can aslo use a hashtable, or in python better known as a dictionary to reduce time complexity to O(n). This is done by copying your items into a dictionary and checking if your item exists as a key already. The value does not matter in this case. Checking if a key exists is done by doing

```
if key in dict
```

and is O(1), making this the fastest approach witha  total of O(n)

an article comparing all 3 methods can be found [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-duplicates-from-an-unsorted-linked-list/). If you select java for the code examples, everything should be clear. Remember that when they use HashSet in java, in python we can just use a dictionary.